# Expected value of sum of polynomials of Gaussians

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, expectation

I want to evaluate and compare the following two expressions:

$$
T_1 = \mathbb{E}\left\{ 
\sum_{p=1}^P \sum_{m=1}^M \left( x_{m}^p \right)^2
\right\} \\
T_2 = \mathbb{E}\left\{ 
\sum_{p=1}^P \sum_{m=1}^M \left( \sum_{n=1}^N d_n x_{N(m-1)+n}^p \right)^2
\right\}, \quad \text{with} \quad \sum_{n=1}^N d_n = 1
$$

where $x_i$ are iid. Gaussian $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ ($i=m$ for the first case and $i=N(m-1)+n$ for the second).

I can show experimentally (in MATLAB) that $T_2 > T_1$ but I fail to show this with algebra.

I think $T_1$ is pretty straight forward:

$$
T_1 = \sum_{p=1}^P \sum_{m=1}^M \mathbb{E}\left\{ x_{m}^{2p} \right\} = M\sum_{p=1}^P \sigma^{2p} (2p-1)!!
$$

For the second case my my attempt is:

$$
T_2 = 
M \sum_{p=1}^P \mathbb{E}\left\{ \left( \sum_{n=1}^N d_n x_{N(m-1)+1}^p \right)^2
\right\} =\\
M \sum_{p=1}^P \mathbb{E}\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^N \left(d_n x_{N(m-1)+n}^p \right)^2 + 2\sum_{n<m} d_n x_{N(m-1)+n}^p d_m x_{N(m-1)+m}^p
\right\}
$$

Since the variables are iid I assume that the second term is zero and I have:

$$
T_2 =
M \sum_{p=1}^P \sum_{n=1}^N d_n^2 \mathbb{E}\left\{ x_{N(m-1)+n}^{2p}
\right\} = T_1 \sum_{n=1}^N d_n^2
$$

But since $\sum_{n=1}^N d_n=1$, $\sum_{n=1}^N d_n^2 < 1$ and hence $T_2 < T_1$.

Is there a mistake in this derivation?

Comment: Are you assuming p is odd? Because otherwise I do not see how the second term in the second case is 0?

Comment: The second term in the second case gets zero because the $x_i$ are iid ($E\{x y\} = E\{x\} E\{y\}=0$ for independent RV)

Comment: Isn't it $$\mathbb{E}{x^p y^p} = \mathbb{E}{x^p}\mathbb{E}{y^p} \neq 0$$ unless p is odd?